# Why do we only consider the support of continuous functions?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

My understanding of the definition of the support (or closed support) of a real-valued function is as follows:

*Let $X$ be a topological space and $f\colon X \to \mathbb{R}$ be a (continuous?) function. Then the support of $f$ is the closure of the set $\{x \in X : f(x) \ne 0 \}$.*

My question is why do I sometimes see the requirement that $f$ be continuous and sometimes it is dropped? My assumption is that if $f$ is not continuous then the support is not particularly helpful. Otherwise I don't see why we should restrict our class of functions so much.

Comment: Continuity isn't required but you're often interested in functions with compact support. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_(mathematics)

Comment: Misprint: replace $=0$ with $\ne0.$

Comment: @CyclotomicField so I assume when we talk about compact support we are only interested in continuous functions since continuous functions play nicely with compact sets?

Comment: The support of functions which are not continuous is still a very useful concept. For a somewhat trivial example, a locally integrable function with compact support is integrable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We're often interested in functions with compact support however continuity is not required. For example we might want to make a digital copy of a song, which is a continuous waveform since sound wiggles our eardrums. The song has a finite length so even in it's continuous form it has compact support since its closure will be bounded. Now if we parameterize the wave over time with $f(t)$ with $0 \leq t \leq 1$ we can digitize it by choosing some increment $\frac1n$ with $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and sample the $n$ points $f(\frac kn)$ for all natural $0 \leq k < n$. These sampled points can be considered a function of their own if we define it to be zero everywhere except the sampled points and will typically be discontinuous at those points. The support in this case is just the set of points $\{0,\frac1n,\frac2n, \dots,\frac{n-2}n,\frac{n-1}n\}$ which is compact despite the discontinuities. Step functions are also a useful class of functions which can have compact support while containing discontinuities.